# Determine the slope and write the Cartesian equation of the line.

Tags: geometry

Write the equation of the line by the origin of coordinates that has vector director of components (1,2)  determine the slope and write the Cartesian equation of the line.

**My attempt:**

Let $l$ a line such that pass for the origin. 
Let $a$ a director vector of $l$. we know  as $a$ is a director vector of $l$ then the components $(1,2)$ are in the line.

We have two points of the line.
We know the general equation for the line is $Ax+By+C=0$

Here i'm stuck can someone help me?

Comment: What is a ‘director vector’?

Comment: is a vector that gives the direction of a line and also orients it, that is to say, gives it a certain sense. @雨が好きな人

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A directing vector of a line is a vector which is collinear to any vector formed by two points on this line.

Now take the point $O(0,0)$ which belongs to the line (as given) and any point $M(x, y) $ on this line. Thus the vector $OM$ is collinear to $(1,2)$; meaning that there exists a real number **$k$** such that $OM=$**k**$a$.

Thus, by comparing their coordinates, we get: $x=k$ and $y=2k$, and thus $y=2x$ is the equation of this line (or $2x-y=0$).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $(1,2)$ is a vector parallel to the line, the line has slope $\frac{2}{1} = 2$.

From this, we can deduce that the Cartesian equation of the line is

$$y = 2x + c$$

for some constant $c$. We cannot determine $c$ unless we are given more information (such as a particular point on the line).

Answer (score 2):

I take it you want the line through the origin and $(1,2)$.  The equation is $y=2x$.  This is in slope-intercept form (slope $2$, $y$-intercept $0$).  The slope is $m=\dfrac {\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\dfrac{2-0}{1-0}=2$.